# Access development server with subdomains from device on same network

Tags: ios, macos

I have a development server that I run locally on my Mac, which is named `mark-mb12`. It has a number of docker containers and exposes a few subdomains (api, www, admin) over https. Because I use https, I've created a local Certificate Authority and certs using my local machine name, so they are for `mark-mb12.local`, `api.mark-mb12.local`, etc.  I modified my /etc/hosts file to define the subdomains, mapping them to `127.0.0.1`.

Everything works just fine on my machine. I can access the `www` and `admin` subdomains in the browser, and my iOS app works against the `api` subdomain when running in the simulator.

From my iPhone, I have it working so that I can access `https://mark-mb12.local` in Safari, so I have the CA installed and trusted.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to access the subdomains from my device or a browser running on a different machine.

Any ideas as to what I need to do?

Comment: You will need a local DNS server on your network with the required entries to point the host names to your MacBook's IP address on the local network. You will then need your other device to use that dns server.  If you can edit the `hosts` file on that other device then you can add entries that point to the IP address of the mbp

Comment: @Paulw11 - thank you!  That did the trick and was much easier to do than I thought it would be.